# Import mongodb data to mongo image

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have dir with `mongo` database backup.
Also, I have running `docker` image of `mongo` db from https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

My goal is to import backup data to mongo image using something like:

`mongorestore -d <database_name> <directory_backup>`

my project structure:

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── mongo-seed
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── backup
│       └── mydb
│           ├── beleagues.bson
│           ├── beleagues.metadata.json
│           ├── bookmakers.bson
│           ├── bookmakers.metadata.json
│           ├── globalstores.bson
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

mongo-seed/Dockerfile:

```
1 FROM mongo
2 COPY backup /backup
3 CMD mongorestore -d mydb /backup
```

docker-compose.yml

```
1 mongodb:
2   image: mongo
3   ports:
4     - "27017:27017"
5
6 mongo-seed:
7   build: ./mongo-seed
8   links:
9     - mongodb
```

after `docker-compose up`:

```
➜  project-dit docker-compose up
Building mongo-seed
Step 1/3 : FROM mongo
 ---> a3639b2a0f13
Step 2/3 : COPY backup /backup
 ---> 5a738f2746b6
Step 3/3 : CMD mongorestore -d mydb /backup
 ---> Running in 6a78a27f2214
Removing intermediate container 6a78a27f2214
 ---> 29908e84d056
Successfully built 29908e84d056
Successfully tagged gepick-tests_mongo-seed:latest
WARNING: Image for service mongo-seed was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating myproject-tests_mongodb_1 ... done
Creating myproject-tests_mongo-seed_1 ... done
Attaching to myproject-tests_mongodb_1, myproject-tests_mongo-seed_1
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.226+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=5ce234000e63
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.10
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.231+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true } }
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.232+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.232+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.232+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.233+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=487M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.657+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1561798095:657331][1:0x7fe1f8d52a80], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.664+0000 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.674+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.674+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.674+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.674+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.676+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with provided UUID: 81dcec38-31d8-438f-b3bd-c55642bafe5e
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.684+0000 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 4.0
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.689+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.startup_log with generated UUID: 713feb5d-26c7-4804-833a-0a01775f5777
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.700+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.702+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.705+0000 I STORAGE  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] createCollection: config.system.sessions with generated UUID: 8a8fdc03-f680-4262-8804-33b92a950eb3
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.720+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index on: config.system.sessions properties: { v: 2, key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", ns: "config.system.sessions", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 }
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.720+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh]     building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:48:15.723+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
mongo-seed_1  | 2019-06-29T08:48:19.291+0000    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
myproject-tests_mongo-seed_1 exited with code 1
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:49:27.463+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54364 #1 (1 connection now open)
mongodb_1     | 2019-06-29T08:49:27.463+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:54364 conn1: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.0.10" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "16.04" } }
```

Comment: You should probably post your `Dockerfile` and/or `docker-compose.yml` and/or the commands you have tried already and what failed.

Comment: Notably your logs are showing `mongorestore` being called before the `mongod` output is indicating that it has started. Basically you need to [wait for mongodb to start](https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+wait+for+mongodb+to+start) before any restore is attempted. Quite a few things around that already discuss that.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the image that you mentioned, Here is the way to go but if its deal with json collection. just correct the path for copy command

```
copy backup /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
>   with extensions .sh and .js that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database
>   specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or
>   test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.

Another way is to up the second container, link it with mongo container and mount the backup directory to container and remove the container after backup is done.

```
 docker run --rm --link mongodb:mongo -v /root:/backup mongo \
 bash -c ‘mongorestore /backup --host mongo:27017’
```

With docker compose change this section and add this command `bash -c ‘mongorestore /backup --host mongo:27017’`

```
6 mongo-seed:
7   build: ./mongo-seed
8   links:
9     - mongodb
```

Or you can also run command inside container.

```
docker exec -i mongo sh -c 'mongorestore --archive' < db.dump
```